# Recipes to update database in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a method for adding stamp to the card, from QR code reader to web service
my question is,

Here is my code:

```
- (void)addStamp
{    
    NSString *url = [_URL stringByAppendingString:@"add-stamp"];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&code=%@", self.userId, self.code ];
    post = [post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[post UTF8String]
                                      length:[post lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
    URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:600];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
}
```

Rightnow I want to update my DB with new method -> if the code is repeated add stamp, if not create add a new card:

```
-(void)addStampInDB:(int)cardId
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication 
    sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"remote_id = %d", cardId];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [managedObjectContext lock];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
    error:&error];
    [managedObjectContext unlock];

    Card *d = nil;
    if([fetchedObjects count] > 0 ){
        d = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cardId++;

    } else{ 
        d = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    }

    NSArray *test;
    for(NSDictionary *stamp in test)
    {   
        d.remote_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[stamp objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
        d.stampNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[stamp objectForKey:@"stampNumber"] intValue]];
        d.createdAt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[stamp objectForKey:@"createdAt"] 
        intValue]];

        [managedObjectContext lock];
        NSError *error;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
            if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
                for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
                    NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
            }
        }
        [managedObjectContext unlock];
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm in a right way or not and also how I can test my method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about your question but I'll try to give some hints.

**First**

```
Card *d = nil;
if([fetchedObjects count] > 0 ){
    d = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    cardId++;

} else{ 
    d = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card" 
                                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
}
```

Here you have found an existing card, you use it, else you create a new. Question: what about `cardId`? Where is it used?

**Second**

```
for(NSDictionary *stamp in test)
{   
    d.remote_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[stamp objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
    d.stampNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[stamp objectForKey:@"stampNumber"] intValue]];
    d.createdAt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[stamp objectForKey:@"createdAt"] 
    intValue]];

    // other code here
}
```

If you loop `test`, you overwrite the value of your card `d` each time. Is it right?

**Third**

```
for(NSDictionary *stamp in test)
{   
    // other code here
}

// save here
```

Move the save out of the for loop. This boost performances in your app. It is not necessary to save each time in your loop. Do it at the end only.

Hope that helps.

P.S. If you want to know something else let me know.

Comment: thank you for your comments cardId it's on the web service, what do you mean by  // other code here and should I do the loop or not?

Comment: @adam about `// other code here` I mean the code you are using. For the sake of simplicity I din't repeat your code.  About the loop, it depends on your requirement. Do you want to overwrite the card each time?